# Which employee has processed most orders?

Tags: sql

I was trying to do my exercise to get an answer to this question,

> --Which employee has processed most orders?

following the table below;
and in SQL the query became this monster

```
select e.employeeid, e.lastname, count(*) as 'aantal' from employee e
 join orders o on e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID group by e.EmployeeID,
 e.LastName  having count(*) = (
                  select top 1 count(*) as 'aantal' from employee e
                  join orders o on e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
                  group by e.FirstName
                  order by count(*) desc
                  )
```

my question is, is there really no other ways to get an answer from this:

```sql
select e.employeeid, e.lastname, count(*) as 'aantal' from employee 
join orders o on e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
group by e.EmployeeID, e.LastName
```

[image: ans to this query]

and then just find a maximum of these table??

like: `max(and here query)`

[image]

Comment: @Shadow how to you "know" this is SQL Server? Certainly `int(11)` is *not* a valid data type is SQL Server, and neither is `longtext`. pl7771 *only* tag the RDBMS you are *really* using, not multiple. Also, please don't put things like your code attempts in quote blocks; just put them in code fences.

Comment: @Larnu I removed the database tag, not the mysql one. However, the sql statement in the question uses top predicate and not the limit clause, so removing mysql seems to be a valid decision!

Comment: Your' eright, it was @GordonLinoff that did, i saw the "editted tag", and assumed both were removed at the same time. Apoligies Shadow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer to my question.
This is just impossible in SQL
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hyCpyhj8Jc&ab_channel=DaveSullivan

Answer (score 0):

You probably can try this:

```
select e.employee_id, e.title, count(o.order_id) as c from orders o join employees e on e.employee_id = o.employee_id group by e.employee_id, e.title order by c desc;
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?